# How to return to app if user cancel Facebook Login?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I m working on facebook login. Everything is fine, when I tap on the login button it will take me to safari (or FB app) and ask me for FB login.

my question is how to make safari return to my app if I decide not to login and hit cancel button? its currently taking me to my facebook main page after hitting cancel and is not useful

thanks in advance!

Comment: when the login is succesful, does it return to your app?

Comment: Check you Facebook url in your app

Comment: janusfidel: yes it did. but not if i tap cancel though, is there a way to solve this? so that cancel or logged in both return back to my app

Comment: @ChrisLin the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do it exactly as you suggest but what you could do is create another view controller with a web view inside of it, and a navigation bar at the top that has a cancel button on it. This way they could log on to facebook from within the app, so they don't have to switch between things which can be a little lengthy! It would also allow an easy cancel button with 'dismissModalViewController' or whatever it has changed to in iOS6. I believe this should work :)